# Window function with dynamic lag

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I am looking at the window slide function for a Spark DataFrame in Spark SQL.

I have a dataframe with columns `id`, `month` and `volume`.

```
id       month   volume new_col
1        201601  100     0
1        201602  120   100
1        201603  450   220
1        201604  200   670
1        201605  121   870
```

Now I want to add a new column with the name `new_col`, the value of `new_col` is the sum of `volume` and `new_col` before the current row, as shown above.
The value of the `new_col` first line will be zero.

I tried below option to use the window function `lag` by using PySpark. But I found that the `new_col` column will be recursively used. The way by only using `lag` function can not do this:

```
window = Window.partitionBy(F.col('id')).orderBy(F.col('month').asc())
df.withColumn('new_col', F.lag(col('volume'), 1).over(window) + F.lag(col('new_col'), 1).over(window))
```

Is there a way to dynamically lag the `new_col` by using window functions? Or are there any other good solutions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` and `sum` over a window to achieve this. `sum` will automatically compute the **cumsum** if used over a window. The below code will first lag the `volume` column and then take its cumsum but doing the operations in the opposite order is also possible.

```
window = Window.partitionBy(F.col('id')).orderBy(F.col('month').asc())
df.withColumn('new_col', F.sum(F.lag(col('volume'), 1, 0).over(window)).over(window))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested window functions

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> 
>>> data = sc.parallelize([
...     (1,'201601',100),
...     (1,'201602',120),
...     (1,'201603',450),
...     (1,'201604',200),
...     (1,'201605',121)])
>>> col = ['id','month', 'volume']
>>> 
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data, col)
>>> df.show()
+---+------+------+
| id| month|volume|
+---+------+------+
|  1|201601|   100|
|  1|201602|   120|
|  1|201603|   450|
|  1|201604|   200|
|  1|201605|   121|
+---+------+------+

>>> window1 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('month')
>>> window2 = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('month').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)
>>> df = df.withColumn('new_col', F.sum(F.lag('volume').over(window1)).over(window2)).na.fill({'new_col': 0})
>>> df.show()
+---+------+------+-------+                                                     
| id| month|volume|new_col|
+---+------+------+-------+
|  1|201601|   100|      0|
|  1|201602|   120|    100|
|  1|201603|   450|    220|
|  1|201604|   200|    670|
|  1|201605|   121|    870|
+---+------+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks very much.
If I want to do "multiply", but not sum. Would should I do? There is no F.multiply function in functions package.

Comment: Ali, can you look at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493277/dynamic-filtering-a-pyspark-dataframe` ? I have not posted it, but I am curious as to how can we solve this using dynamic `lead` or some other method. Thanks for your consideration.